# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Super User breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                106        337
Users destroyed                               3,777          0
Users deleted                                    24          0
Users contacted                                 153          0
User suspensions lifted early                     5          0
User banned from review                           0         19
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           467     22,226
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               15      6,273
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         43     17,709
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                2     14,168
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                24     40,710
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               93     26,001
Tags merged                                       6          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          0
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Revisions redacted                               18          0
Questions unprotected                             2          4
Questions reopened                              217        243
Questions protected                               5        894
Questions migrated                              829        142
Questions merged                                  6          0
Questions flagged⁴                              587     18,138
Questions closed                              6,820      4,860
Question flags handled⁴                       4,065     14,660
Posts unlocked                                   15        225
Posts undeleted                                 100        609
Posts locked                                     11      5,258
Posts deleted⁵                                7,790     29,709
Posts bumped                                      0     17,462
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               64          0
Comments flagged                                 35     16,052
Comments deleted⁶                            11,128     24,244
Comment flags handled                         8,426      7,661
Bounties canceled                                10          0
Answers flagged                               1,036     21,288
Answer flags handled                         17,830      4,494
All comments on a post moved to chat             58          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Super User](https://superuser.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://superuser.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Any statistics on how many of the deleted posts were spam? Any statistics on how many of the closed questions are duplicates vs other stuff, and out of the duplicates, how many were by gold badge users wielding the mighty Mjølnir?

Comment: For what it's worth, Smoke Detector has 3904 spam reports from Super User in 2018. The peak days were January 4, July 23, and November 29, with 25 spam posts each. There is one day without spam reports, February 18 (could be a Smoke Detector outage, haven't checked). Some of these reports will have been false positives.