# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Super User over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  79        370
Users destroyed³                               3,620          0
Users deleted                                     15          0
Users contacted                                  109          0
User banned from review                            1         33
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            237     23,805
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                 3      5,989
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue           8     16,752
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                 0     14,247
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 58     54,391
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue                37     20,502
Tags merged                                        3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              3          0
Tag synonyms created                               3          0
Revisions redacted                                13          0
Questions unprotected                              2         27
Questions reopened                               144        172
Questions protected                                8      1,197
Questions migrated                             1,974        192
Questions merged                                   3          0
Questions flagged⁵                               881     17,712
Questions closed                               9,391      3,797
Question flags handled⁵                        5,216     13,372
Posts unlocked                                    30        358
Posts undeleted                                  112        769
Posts locked                                       8      6,381
Posts deleted⁶                                 8,242     35,027
Posts bumped                                       0     17,238
Escalations to the Community Manager team          9          0
Comments undeleted                                53          0
Comments flagged                                  27     14,897
Comments deleted⁷                              7,076     25,805
Comment flags handled                          5,002      9,924
Bounties canceled                                 11          0
Answers flagged                                1,177     20,579
Answer flags handled                          18,096      3,658
All comments on a post moved to chat              47          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Super User](https://superuser.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://superuser.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13495/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: I figure into your Footnotes 2 and 7 above. Does the list above clear and we start over? or is it Cumulative?   Thank you for any information you may be able to provide.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, @john; suspensions are time-based, so when they're up then they're up.

Comment: So if / when I run afoul of the rules again (my best expertise generally) I start again.  Thanks

Comment: @John - There typically isn’t any starting over.  If you are suspended, and create a new user, your suspension follows to your new profile

Comment: So if I make the same error 5 years on, I am still subject to the same penalty as if both were created within 30 days of each other. That was the gist of my query. You say there is never any forgiveness in this place. I thought so, then with the first answer I thought there might be, but apparently not

Comment: Wait moderators only moved 47 threads to chat in the entire year? Is this a change compared to previous years?

Comment: I'm surprised I don't see "tags deleted" here. That is a very commonly discussed issue on Meta.

Comment: Oh -- now I see, this is Super User, not Stack Overflow. I was thinking of that Meta.  Do they do these statistics for the main Meta?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Are you perhaps thinking of the main SO rather than SU?

Comment: @JosiahYoder Yeah, I thought this is Meta SO.